# ElasticSearch multi_match query not working

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm using elastic search 5.3 and have this super simple multi_match query. None of the documents contains the ridiculous query, neither in title nor content. Still ES gives me plenty of matches.

```
{
  "query" : {    
      "multi_match" : {
        "query" : "42a6o8435a6o4385q023bf50",
        "fields" : [              
          "title","content"
        ],
        "type" : "best_fields",
        "operator" : "AND",
        "minimum_should_match" : "100%"            
      } 
    }
  }
}
```

The analyzer for content is "english" and for title it is this one:

```
"analyzer": {
    "english_autocomplete": {
      "tokenizer":  "standard",
      "filter": [
          "lowercase",
          "english_stop",
          "english_stemmer",
          "autocomplete_filter"
      ]
    }
  }

"autocomplete_filter": { 
     "type": "edge_ngram",
     "min_gram": 1,
     "max_gram": 20
}
```

Am I missing something or how can I tell ES not to do that?

Comment: What are the types of your `title` and `content` fields? analyzed string?

Comment: And how are you sending your query?

Comment: analyzers: title is "english_autocomplete" and content is "english"
I am sending the query as JSON to the API

Comment: Since you have a custom analyzer, it would be wise to also add it to your question, as it plays a big role.